# Matlab error for matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, dimensions, pattern-recognition

I get an error

```
  Error using  - 
    Matrix dimensions must agree.

    Error in Untitled6 (line 32)
        temp=double(S_bar) - (repmat(mean_face, 1, num_images));
```

code :

```
for i=1:num_images
    [m,n] = size(S(:,i))
    [a,b] = size(repmat(mean_face, 1, num_images))
    temp=double(S(:,i)) - (repmat(mean_face, 1, num_images));
```

size of S(:,i) is [45045 1] and size of repmat(mean_face, 1, num_images  is [45045 45]
So i tried to use the transpose of S(:,i) so the dimensions become [1 45045] so that i can get a resulting matrix of [1 45]. But even when i use the transpose i get the same error. Why am i getting the error even though the matrix dimensions are correct?

Comment: You can't subtract a 45045x1 matrix minus a 45045x45 matrix. What is the intended result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do what i believe is called "broadcasting", i.e. making sure elementwise operations on matrices are done on matrices of compatible sizes. One elegant way of doing this is using bsxfun :

```
temp=bsxfun(@minus,double(S(:,i)),(repmat(mean_face, 1, num_images)));
```

You could also use `repmat` on your `double(S(:,i))` so that it has the right number of columns.

Hope this helps,

Tepp